# Including many header files together without producing errors

Tags: c++, loops, include, pragma

i have a bit of a tricky problem here. I have 3 classes: agent, campaign, and sale - and they all need to include each other, how can i do this without causing a million errors in VS, I've already tried the ifndef guard and pragma once.

Comment: Forward declaration. That's all you need...

Comment: I already tried adding class classINeed before all of the code and it ends up with another error - "may not use class with no definition" or something along those lines...

Comment: tl;dr. But I did notice that `agent` contains a `sale` member and a `sale` contains an `agent` member. This recursive containership won't work.

Comment: Why the semicolons after the includes with ""?

Comment: Well what am i suppose to do about that charles? thats my question. Im already aware of that lol

Comment: Make the agent have a sale id, which is an int?

Comment: @Toxicz How do you think such a datastructure would be represented in a finite amount of memory? Agent contains a sale, which contains an agent, which contains a sale, which contains ...

Comment: Your header files only need to "include each other" because your design is flawed; once you've fixed your class design your header files won't need to include each other and this problem will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is way more code than I wanted to see.*

In essence, as we have said in the comments you have made everything rely on everything else which can never work.

If you introduce a level of indirection, e.g. make an agent remember a sales id, which is an int, you won't need all headers to include all other headers.
Is there a chance that an agent might make more than one sale?
If you, instead of `sale agent_item_sales;` you could store them in a vector

```
std::vector<int> agent_item_sales;
```

However, you never use this member variable, so perhaps you can just delete it?